# In vim, how do I delete a word?

Tags: vim, vi

I have a big bear in my bed.

Suppose I have the cursor on "bear", in the "e" position, how would I delete the word "bear" completely?

Comment: possible duplicate of [delete word after or around cursor in VIM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/833838/delete-word-after-or-around-cursor-in-vim)

Comment: yes (both questions should be merged) and no (both questions are different). The other question concerns the insert-MODE. This one concerns the NORMAL-mode.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You could maybe check this out.. [delete word after or around cursor in VIM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833838/delete-word-after-or-around-cursor-in-vim).
Seems similar to what you need..

Normal mode:

```
    daw : delete the word under the cursor    
    caw : delete the word under the cursor and put you in insert mode
```

Comment: Yes, this is what he needs. Delete the whole word while the cursor is anywhere inside the word.

Comment: could you please explain how this actually works? d or c is the verb, a is ???, and w is word.

Comment: @DennisHodapp, a stands for "around". daw deletes the word under the cursor, and a whitespace character either before or after the word.

Answer (score 23):

<kbd>b</kbd> to jump to start of word, then <kbd>dw</kbd> to delete current word.

Comment: @TIMEX -- Nope, not silly at all, just a different way of thinking that's just as good as `daw`.

Comment: Text-objects are indeed great, but that doesn't make other methods "silly".

Answer (score 10):

As an alternative to [larsmans answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857105/in-vim-how-do-i-delete-a-word/6857137#6857137), you could go back with <kbd>b</kbd> and then **d** elete everything un **t** il the next space: <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>space</kbd>.

This mnemonic is more general and you could use it with several separators.

If you want to delete backward, use <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>T</kbd><kbd>space</kbd>.

To learn more left-right-motions, ask for [`:he left-right-motions`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#left-right-motions) and read the end of the chapter.

Comment: +1 Not sure it is the best for this situation, but it should come in handy. Is there a way to do this in reverse, so we can delete until the previous space/character?

Comment: @The Talking Walnut: no problem. Updated answer.

Answer (score 9):

`diw`/`daw` ! -> `:h text-objects`

Forget `bdt`/`bdw` here.