# VIM - How to delete a word in the INSERT mode?

Tags: vim

How to delete a word in the `INSERT mode`? 
I'm usually using **CTRL+W** to delete from the cursor to the beginning of the previous word. Is there a shortcut to do the same but with opposite  direction?

Comment: possible duplicate of [delete word after or around cursor in VIM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/833838/delete-word-after-or-around-cursor-in-vim)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There's no built-in command for that but you can create your own easily:

```
inoremap <key> <C-o>de
```

Comment: This is a best solution ever I've seen. It even work well where cursor is at end of line. also we can use this for backward deletion like `inoremap <C-b> <C-o>db`

Answer (score 1):

@romainl's answer didn't work for me, so here's how I did it.

```
inoremap <C-q> <ESC>ldei
```

Answer (score 1):

I was actually looking for the answer for `vscodevim`. If you're like me the answer is simple: there's a build-in shortcut in vscode so we can just add the following to `settings.json`:

```json
"vim.insertModeKeyBindings": [
{
  // Delete one word forward in Insert Mode
  "before": ["<C-e>"],
  "commands": ["deleteWordRight"]
}
]
```

Comment: Hi. Where do you exactly write this?

Comment: @bluesky777 hello I've updated my answer.