# how to make ctr del in vim?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I have tried map in insert mode (:inoremap) this:

```
:inoremap C-D <esc>eviwxa
```

so it can delete word when my cursor is at the beginning of word (as opposed to `ctr+backspace` at the end of word). But that `<C-D>` doesn't work. I had some problems with mapping `ctr-backspace` too, but found solution: `<C-h>` although I don't understand what the `h` stands for. So is it similar to `ctr-del`? does it have also special char for del key?

PS : commands `C-D` and `c-h` were in sharp brackets, so that is not the problem.

Comment: You can delete a word backward with the built-in insert mapping `<C-w>`. For forward deletion of a word, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833838/delete-word-after-or-around-cursor-in-vim). Note that `<C-d>` is not the same as `<C-Del>`

Comment: Ctrl-H (just like some other Ctrl combinations) emit a control character at ASCII position `(x - 64)`, where `x` is the ASCII position of the key. Ctrl-H is thus ASCII 8, also known as BS, or [Backspace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backspace).

Comment: If _commands C-D and c-h was in sharp brackets_, why do you write it differently above?

Comment: because when i include those brackets, this editor (in stack) has somehow havent include them ( as saw it in the preview, how it will look like). Therefor to not mislead others i havent added them.